# Массив ссылок на рисунки в ресурсах

Tags: android, массивы, android-sdk, парсер

Как спарсить R.drawable.(имя файла картинки) в Integer [] массив?

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Так `R.drawable.(имя файла картинки)` это же и есть `Integer`.

можно вот так, например:

```
Integer[] images = {
R.drawable.apple, R.drawable.mango, R.drawable.banana };
```

или вы неверно сформулировали вопрос. Может вам нужно найти ресурс по имени? 
тогда

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("имя_картинки" , "drawable", getPackageName());
```